# Yeoman Angular Generator Grunt Build scripts/vendor.js is Empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have generated an angular project via `yo angular [project-name]`, tried building it via `grunt build`. I checked the `dist/scripts/vendor.d41d8cd9.js` file and I see it empty.  I found [this](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/164) issue and it didn't help me at all. If anyone can point me to the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer somehow, I changed the build:js tag from:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->

<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

to:

```
<!-- build:js(./) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->

<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and it solved my problem :)

Comment: Dude, you totally save me from hours of frustration :D thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed. but dammit, I feel like a flippen noob with this build system...such cryptic! Much directive!

Comment: Same here. Thanks dude. But still, I'm extremely upset with the Yeoman team. How on Earth can they release such a crap?! And it's not the first time. It's a very basic scenario to test before releasing. Too bad. Yeoman is so great, why squander its reputation ?

Comment: This was fixed at some point up to version 0.9.2 of generator-angular. I've noticed the same error when using 0.9.0-1 (As suggested the Yeoman codelab).

Comment: interesting. i had to do direct opposite of this. I guess it has something to do with paths...